# Shape Tween using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shapes, tween

Latest Flash Professional has 3 kind of tweens using timeline: Motion Tween, Shape Tween and Classic Tween.

I made classic tweens using flash Tween class or external scripts like Tweener or Tweenlite.

But is it possible to create a "Shape Tween" using just AS3?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You're thinking of the kind of 'morphing' shapetween that Flash has, right? Those are not available in AS3-code. You could try to workaround that by tweening different parts of a shape by yourself, but it will be a lot more work and I don't think you'll ever be able to make it look as nice.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manipulate each coordinate point in the shape.

You can see a similar example here:

http://wonderfl.net/c/rYzh